# CSS. Show TFOOT only when TBODY has no rows

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a HTML table, with `<thead>` + `<tbody>` + `<tfoot>`. I need to show `<tfoot>` only when `<tbody>` has no rows. I know how to do it with JS/jQuery, but maybe there is a pure CSS solution?

Comment: A question should be self-contained, without implying the title.

Comment: You should clarify what TBODY refers to. A `tbody` element immediately preceding the `tfoot` element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ksmL/5/) (Show `tfoot` when `tbody` has no rows)

```
table tbody:empty + tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

table tbody + tfoot {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

Hide `tfoot` when `tbody` has some content

```
table tbody:not(:empty) + tfoot {
    display: block;
}

table tbody + tfoot {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ksmL/6/)

---

Explanation:

Too many revisions, I just wanted to provide 2 selectors, first is `table tbody:empty + tfoot` which will select `tfoot` if the `tbody` **IS EMPTY**, and the second one is `table tbody:not(:empty) + tfoot` which will select `tfoot` if `tbody` **IS NOT** empty.

> Note: I am using `+` which is an adjacent selector, so as you see, I
>   have `tfoot` element, after the `tbody` element, if it is before
>   `tbody` than you need to use `JS` or `jQuery` as you select reverse in
>   CSS. Also, make sure you use `display: table-footer-group;` as pointed by Mr Lister for `tfoot` element and not <s>`display: block;`</s>

Comment: The code *hides* a `tfoot` when the preceding `tbody` has no rows. The question was how to *show* it only in that case.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for pointing it out, selector was perfect, just need to add 1 more :)

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid it can be done with CSS only in the case that the `tbody` element is completely empty and does not contain even whitespace. For example,

```
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

is not empty, as it contains a linebreak (it has a text node child containing a line break). The [`:empty` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo) matches only elements that have no children at all.

*If* you can count on having the `tbody` element strictly as `<tbody></tbody>` when it has no rows, you can use

```
tbody:not(:empty) + tfoot {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the whitespace counts. But that was not a problem for me.